# Multiple Subqueries With QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I need help converting this sql query into QueryOver Nhibernate criteria.

```
select distinct * from event e where e.name like '%req%' 
or e.Id in (select r.eventId from requirement r where r.name like '%req%') 
or e.Id in (select r.eventId from requirement r where r.id 
in (select s.requirementId from solution s where s.name like '%sol%'))

var queryOver = session.QueryOver<Event>()
                       .Where(x => x.Name.IsInsensitiveLike("%"+searchTerms[1]+"%"))
                       .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn).Asc;
```

So far I have the main query but couldn't find enough reference material on how to add the subqueries. Haven't been successful using joinQueryOver.

Event has one-to-many rel with requirement and requirement has one-to-many rel with solution.

```
  Requirement reqAlias = null;
  Solution solAlias = null;

  var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Event>()                                
      .JoinAlias(x => x.Requirements, () => reqAlias)
      .Where(x => x.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(searchTerms[2]))
      .JoinAlias(() => reqAlias.Solutions, () => solAlias)
      .Where(x => x.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(searchTerms[3]))
      .Select(Projections.Group<Event>(x => x.Id));

  var events = session.QueryOver<Event>()
      .Where(x => x.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(searchTerms[1]))
      .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(subQuery)
      .List().ToList();
```

still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `IsInsensitiveLike` NHibernate appends the `%` after parsing, and uses `lower` to do a lower case comparison. In your code, you are appending the `%` yourself, which results in,

```
select distinct * from event e where e.name like %lower('%req%')%
```

which in turn, doesn't work.

Also, you have 3 subqueries, no a big one, so you need to restructure your code to account for that:

```
select r.eventId from requirement r where r.name like '%req%'
```

to

```
var firstQuery = QueryOver.Of<Requirement>()                                
                          .Where(r => r.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(searchTerms[2]))
                          .Select(r => r.EventId);
```

then,

```
select s.requirementId from solution s where s.name like '%sol%'
```

to

```
var solutionQuery = QueryOver.Of<Solution>()                                
                           .Where(s => s.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(searchTerms[3]));
```

then,

```
select r.eventId from requirement r where r.id 
in (select s.requirementId from solution s where s.name like '%sol%')
```

to

```
var requirementQuery = QueryOver.Of<Requirement>()
                                .WithSubquery
                                .WhereProperty(r => r.Id).In(solutionQuery)
                                .Select(r => r.EventId);
```

Then you need to construct the main query using `Restrictions.Or` to include the 3 queries.

Comment: rae1n Please take a look above. I edited the query based on your suggestion and still no luck. I guess I am having hard time figuring out including the subqueries. Could you please give me an example on how to write the subqueries when more than two tables are involved?

Comment: Thanks, rae1n! that worked like a charm. I had to wing it with HQL until I have time to work on it again...